# how to automatically submit form using which uses ajax and asp?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, submit

I want to get details from one site. That web page is having 3 different select box:
1) Choose Branch
2) Choose Semester
3) Choose Exam Year and then click on show button. This site is using AJAX to show table(output).

I tried with HTML dom parser but don't know the parameters to be passed with that. How to automize such thing which works(submit) with AJAX?

My code is:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://www.abc.com/Engineering-Degree/ExamPapers/ExamPapers.aspx");      

foreach($html->find('select[id=Branch]') as $branchSelect)
{
    echo $branchSelect;
    foreach($html->find('select[id=Semester]') as $semSelect)
    {
        echo $semSelect;
        foreach($html->find('select[id=Exam]') as $examSelect)
        {
            echo $examSelect;
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Show' id='BranchSemesterExamBtn'/>";          
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those selects are using get method to retrieve data maybe. Goto you browser console(F12) and change those select options. You may get the links there.

Comment: Changing select options in browser console doesn't make any difference I guess. It is fetching data from server so definitely I need some mechanism, right? I need some code which can select some options from this drop boxes and each time can copy link from that.

Comment: sometimes there are ajax post on change of select inputs. If not you have to parse from that html. can i have that link?

Comment: I need to download papers from this link: http://www.gtuinfo.in/Engineering-Degree/ExamPapers/ExamPapers.aspx

Comment: the onclick requests are server side here, wont be that much help. can you write greasemonkey script?